# Oracle is not showing error in Sub-Query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

In Oracle why sub-query issue is not reflected when update statement.This Query runs without any  exception or error.

```
update rdt_order set recepientcode ='szdwyes',
vendornad = (select contactnad from rdt_organization where oucode ='szdwyes')
```

Here , contactnad  invalid identifier issue comes when run as seperate query.

```
(select contactnad from rdt_organization where oucode ='szdwyes')
```

Please help me to understand why this happens.

**Table Decscription :**

```
SQL> desc rdt_organization;
Name            Type          Nullable Default Comments 
--------------- ------------- -------- ------- -------- 
ID              INTEGER                                 
PARENTID        INTEGER       Y                         
HEADUSERID      INTEGER       Y                         
DUNS            VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
ORGTYPE         INTEGER       Y                         
OUCODE          VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
FUCODE          VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
ORGNAME         VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
LONGNAME        VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
COMPREGNUM      VARCHAR2(64)  Y                         
TAXREFNUM       VARCHAR2(64)  Y                         
GROUPNAME       VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
ACTIVATIONDATE  DATE          Y                         
EXPIRYDATE      DATE          Y                         
REGDATE         DATE          Y                         
STATUS          INTEGER       Y                         
CONTACTNADID    INTEGER       Y                         
LASTUPDATEDATE  DATE          Y                         
LASTUPDATEDBY   VARCHAR2(15)  Y                         
DEFAULTTIMEZONE VARCHAR2(16)  Y                         
DEFAULTLANGUAGE INTEGER       Y                         
DEFAULTCURRENCY INTEGER       Y                         
COMPANYNAME     VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
LASTUPDATEIP    VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
UNITNAME        VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
TURNOVER        NUMBER(22,6)  Y                         
NOOFEMPLOYEES   INTEGER       Y                         
CONTROLLER      INTEGER       Y                         

SQL> desc rdt_order;
Name               Type          Nullable Default Comments 
------------------ ------------- -------- ------- -------- 
ID                 INTEGER                                 
TRANSID            INTEGER       Y                         
CONTROLLERID       INTEGER                                 
ORGTRANSREF        VARCHAR2(128) Y                         
DOCNUM             VARCHAR2(128) Y                         
BARCODENUM         VARCHAR2(128) Y                         
REFNUM             VARCHAR2(128) Y                         
SUBTYPE            VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
GENDATE            DATE          Y                         
STATUS             INTEGER       Y                         
ISSUEDATE          DATE          Y                         
CANCELDATE         DATE          Y                         
REVISIONDATE       DATE          Y                         
REVISIONNUM        VARCHAR2(6)   Y                         
BATCHNUM           VARCHAR2(128) Y                         
ORGINATORCODE      VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
APPROVERCODE       VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
APPROVERUSER       INTEGER       Y                         
ORGINATORUSER      VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
SENDERMAILBOXID    VARCHAR2(64)  Y                         
RECEPIENTMAILBOXID VARCHAR2(64)  Y                         
RECEPIENTCODE      VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
REMARKS1           VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
REMARKS2           VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
INTERNALNOTE       VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
TERMSCOND          BLOB          Y                         
WFCODE             VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
ORIGINATORDUNS     VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
RECEPIENTDUNS      VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
SHIPTOPLANTCODE    VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
ORDERBYPLANTCODE   VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
CUSTOMERCODE       VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
CUSTOMERNAD        INTEGER       Y                         
BUDGETCODE         VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
ACCOUNTCODE        VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
CONTRACTCODE       VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
MODEL              VARCHAR2(128) Y                         
SHIPPERCODE        VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
VENDORCODE         VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
WHCODE             VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
FWCODE             VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
TRAFFICCODE        VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
TARRIFCODE         VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
FININSTCODE        VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
CUSTOMSCODE        VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
PURCHASEGROUP      VARCHAR2(128) Y                         
MSGFUNCTIONCODE    VARCHAR2(64)  Y                         
BUYERCODE          VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
SHIPTOLOCATION     VARCHAR2(64)  Y                         
BILLTOCODE         VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
FUNDCODE           VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
CONSIGNEECODE      VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
CONTACTCODE        VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
CONTACTNAD         INTEGER       Y                         
FUNDNAD            INTEGER       Y                         
CONSIGNEENAD       INTEGER       Y                         
ACCOUNTNAD         INTEGER       Y                         
PROJECTNAD         INTEGER       Y                         
CONTRACTNAD        INTEGER       Y                         
SHIPPERNAD         INTEGER       Y                         
VENDORNAD          INTEGER       Y                         
WHNAD              INTEGER       Y                         
FWNAD              INTEGER       Y                         
TRAFFICNAD         INTEGER       Y                         
TARRIFNAD          INTEGER       Y                         
FININSTNAD         INTEGER       Y                         
CUSTOMSNAD         INTEGER       Y                         
BUYERNAD           INTEGER       Y                         
SHIPTOLOCATIONNAD  INTEGER       Y                         
BILLTONAD          INTEGER       Y                         
PROJECTCODE        VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
CURRENCYCODE       INTEGER       Y                         
SUBPROJECTCODE     VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
COSTCENTRE         VARCHAR2(64)  Y                         
TOTALAMOUNT        NUMBER(22,6)  Y                         
TOTALITEMS         INTEGER       Y                         
CLASSIFICATION1    VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
CLASSIFICATION2    VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
CLASSIFICATION3    VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
FRIEGHT            VARCHAR2(128) Y                         
PAYMENTTERM1       VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
PAYMENTTERM2       VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
PRICETERM2         VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
PRICETERM1         VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
SHIPMENTTERM1      VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
SHIPMENTTERM2      VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
INSURANCE1         VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
INSURANCE2         VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
SHIPMENTMODE       VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
VALIDFROM          DATE          Y                         
VALIDTO            DATE          Y                         
ACTIONSTATUS       INTEGER       Y                         
LATEST             INTEGER       Y                         
LASTUPDATEBY       VARCHAR2(15)  Y                         
LASTUPDATE         DATE          Y                         
LASTUPDATESTKHID   INTEGER       Y                         
CREATEDBY          INTEGER       Y                         
BEHALFOF           INTEGER       Y                         
PROCESSDEFID       INTEGER       Y                         
PROCESSID          INTEGER       Y                         
CLOSED             INTEGER       Y                         
APPREVNUM          VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
APPREVDATE         DATE          Y                         
XTRACODE1          VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
XTRACODE2          VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
XTRACODE3          VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
XTRACODE4          VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
XTRACODE5          VARCHAR2(32)  Y                         
XTRASTRING1        VARCHAR2(128) Y                         
XTRASTRING2        VARCHAR2(128) Y                         
XTRASTRING3        VARCHAR2(128) Y                         
XTRASTRING4        VARCHAR2(128) Y                         
XTRASTRING5        VARCHAR2(128) Y                         
XTRABIGSTRING1     VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
XTRABIGSTRING2     VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
XTRABIGSTRING3     VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
XTRABIGSTRING4     VARCHAR2(256) Y                         
XTRABLOB1          BLOB          Y                         
XTRABLOB2          BLOB          Y                         
XTRABLOB3          BLOB          Y                         
XTRANUM1           NUMBER        Y                         
XTRANUM2           NUMBER        Y                         
XTRANUM3           NUMBER        Y                         
XTRANUM4           NUMBER        Y                         
XTRANUM5           NUMBER        Y                         
XTRAINT1           INTEGER       Y                         
XTRAINT2           INTEGER       Y                         
XTRAINT3           INTEGER       Y                         
XTRAINT4           INTEGER       Y                         
XTRAINT5           INTEGER       Y                         
XTRDATE1           DATE          Y                         
XTRDATE2           DATE          Y                         
XTRDATE3           DATE          Y                         

SQL>
```

Comment: Perhaps there is a `contactnad` column in `rdt_order`?

Comment: YES you are right.but I  have mentioned contactnad from rdt_organization then still it can chcek with rdt_order?, thanks for reply.

Comment: could you post the two tables `desc`. It would be much easier to identify the problem with structure.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , Thanks for reply.Could you give me a link regarding this Standard which will helpful for my reference.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ,please make it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as specified in the SQL standard. Any sub-query (implicitly) has access to all columns from the "outer" table. If a column is not found in the inner query, a matching column from the outer query will be used.

This is documented in the Oracle manual:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries007.htm#SQLRF52357

> *If columns in a subquery have the same name as columns in the containing statement, then you must prefix any reference to the column of the table from the containing statement with the table name or alias*

In general it is highly recommended to always use a table alias for every table in your query (and use it for every column that you access) if your query uses more than one table.

Comment: Thanks horse for your Answer.